# trying to do an internal transfer, but getting resistance from the upper managers

Tags: internal-transfer

I work at a Dow 30 company and I'm not too happy with my current role. I applied to a role (in another business unit) in my company and the hiring manager is highly interested. I will have the last round of interview next week.

My boss was originally supportive and said good words about me. Once I got to the final round of interview, boss's boss is not happy that I might leave and wants me to stay another 6 month to finish a project (one that I barely started).

I feel 6 month is way too long to be unhappy, and is honestly unnecessarily long for a transition period. It's not like they won't survive without me.

My boss asked the hiring manager if the last round of interview (panel) should still take place given that I'm not going anywhere for 6 month. The hiring manager said to let the pipeline continue and "we'll see".

I'd be happy to stick it out another 2 month, but no way 6 month. I feel my management is trying to take me out of consideration for the internal role by specifying such a long transition time. FYI, I've been at my current role for 2+ years.

Advice?

thanks

Comment: From what you say they have told you, I don't think you will be changing position, time to decide what you want to do.

Comment: "Not goint anywhere for 6 months". Make your boss and your boss boss aware you can somwhere in much less time if you give them your notice.

Comment: This is "candid conversation with hiring manager" territory. Have you spoken to him about this? Do you know whether there's "bad blood" between them?

Comment: Can you quit and be re-hired?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite clear that you do not want to continue being in the current team for another 6 months, so I will not brainstorm on this alternative.

Then you have two alternatives:

1. You move to the other team.
2. You move to another company.

You might want to go the following route, which I consider to be the safest:

1. You go job hunting, no joke;
2. once you have a good deal, you go to your current boss and tell him that he can choose: he lets you go to the other department, or you go to the other company; win-win for you;
3. talk to the hiring manager; see if he is willing to match (or exceed) the salary you would get from the other company;
4. based on all the info you have now, make your decision.

Comment: *I'd be happy to stick it out another 2 month* - Don't do this. Don't offer a compromise of any kind. If your current managers want to keep you in your current position they should offer inducements and rewards to compensate you for staying, not sabotage your application and negotiation with the hiring manager. You should not negotiate with those who seek unfairly to harm you.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are a lot of missing details, it seems like there are two relevant facts:

- the hiring manager in the other business unit has a need that you can fill,
- your boss (and his boss) in your current business unit has a need that you can fill.

Staying for 6 months implies that your current business unit's needs are more important than the other's.  But here's the thing: that's not your decision.  Nor is it your boss's, or his boss's (unless he heads both units). Instead that's something for the leaders of the two business units to resolve between themselves.  And from experience, that other business unit will have very little sympathy for your current unit when it comes to an employee who wants to transfer.

So I'd recommend a quiet chat with the hiring manager, and let him know that you're really excited to move to the new unit and you want to do so as soon as possible.  With the other business unit fighting for you, it's quite likely that your current boss (and his boss) won't be in a position to do much about it.

Answer (score 1):

> that I might leave and wants me to stay another 6 month to finish a
> project (one that I barely started).

Given that you've barely started this project, the 6 months deadline is probably going to end up being 12 months or 24 months instead.

Start interviewing with external employers as well. Since there is little you can do to control the internal political system of your company, you must plan for the worst.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in your situation a few times. The ability to move internally is blocked by your current management. In some cases it is their attempt to stop somebody from leaving. They know that if you look externally they can't stop you, so they stop you the only way they can.

When current management is consulted while evaluating internal candidates for jobs, there is always the risk that the current management will either block the transfer or downplay your skills to make sure you don't get offered the new position.

The companies that I know handle this well don't allow the current manager to even know you have applied. The hiring team can see your employee file and your annual reviews without needed to contact them. That eliminates the temptation of interfering. The first time they know about it is when you give them the notice your are changing projects. To eliminate too much job hopping they block internal transfers for 6 months to a year after making a switch.

In a company I worked for that handled this poorly the only option for good employees to switch is when higher management forced the issue, or when a current contract was about to end. If the delays lasted long enough people just left the company.

I would let the current situation play out, it is possible that the new project will decide to pick you and wait for the deadline. In the mean time I would look outside the company. That way if the deadline is extended and then you get a good external offer, you can then leave. In this case both managers will be upset, and the company might eventually see the problem.